# How to separate text in label which uses a Variable size

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My program takes a users input, the input can be quite long, part of the program is too display that text, so far i have manager to get the text to be shown, however, the text carries out off the fixed size screen

how can i get my program to seperate the text so that it can only go so far and then the message continues on the next line
[image: image shows part of the intended message]

```
    cursor.execute(findPlayerTeamname, [(playerTeamname)])
    temp = cursor.fetchall()
    temp = temp[0][0]

    message = StringVar()
    message.set(temp)

    messageLabel = Label(canvas, text = "Notice:")
    messageLabel.place(x = 30, y = 60)
    messageLabel.configure(bg = "grey90", fg = "royalblue", font=("Arial Nova", 25))    

    updatedMessageLabel = Label(canvas, textvariable = message)
    updatedMessageLabel.place(x = 30, y = 120)
    updatedMessageLabel.configure(bg = "grey90", fg = "royalblue", font=("Arial Nova", 16))
```

Comment: If you want to wrap the text, you need to know the `width` (in pixel) of the label (since you use `place` layout manager).  Then you can add, for example, `width=300` in `.place(...)` and `wraplength=updatedMessageLabel.winfo_width()` option to `.configure(...)`.  However, you need to add `root.update()` (assume `root` is `Tk()`) before `.configure(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `textwrap` module.

```
from tkinter import *
import textwrap

root = Tk()
text = "This is a very long sentence that needs wrapping else it will run out of space"
Label(root,text=textwrap.fill(text,20)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```